# All controllers and constructors run twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .net core web project. This is identity project. I have developed Identityserver4.

But I noticed something, all methods constructor methods works twice.

Now, no layout, no javascript, not hyperlink, no any element.
I tried everything. I couldn't find a solution.
I added a new controller. It's just a blank file.
It's weird, but he's been called twice.

I cleared the browser cache. I tried it with the hidden tab. I tried a different browser. Nothing's changed. I haven't had a solution in 5 hours.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
   return Content("Test");
}
```

If need my startup class is :
What can I do?

```
public class Startup
    {
        public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
        public static IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; set; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings." + env.EnvironmentName + ".json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            HostingEnvironment = env;
        }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, SmsSender>();
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();


            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            })
               .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
               .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
               .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
               .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
               .AddProfileService<IdentityWithAdditionalClaimsProfileService>();

            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();


            services.AddAuthentication()
                 .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                 {
                     options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Authority");
                     options.ApiName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiName");
                     options.ApiSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiSecret");
                     options.EnableCaching = true;
                     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                 });


            services.AddMvcCore(
            options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());
            })
            .AddJsonFormatters()
            .AddAuthorization();
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Give us specific examples. There's nothing extraordinary about your startup (though it's *super* odd that you're building a new configuration instead of just injecting it into the constructor).

Comment: Yes, but the negative code you notice is not about the error I'm talking about.

Comment: How else can I give a specific example? No layout, no html, no empty img tag, no empty href tag.

Comment: How can you have a controller in a blank file?

Comment: [AllowAnonymous]
Route("Sample")]
    public class SampleController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("Index")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("TEST");
        }
    }

This runs twice.

Comment: Make sure the browser clears the cache? Have you tried using e.preventdefault?

Comment: Press F12 in the browser. Switch to the Network tab. Load the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit difficult though.
Some small plugins cause this. For example [WhatRuns](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatruns/cmkdbmfndkfgebldhnkbfhlneefdaaip)

I disabled this small plugins, and the problem is solved. Then I reactivated it and called again twice.

There may be a lot of reasons, by the way. I checked all those problems one by one. I list these one by one.

1. I have deleted Chrome cache
2. Change the a to a button type=button
3. return false from the event handler
4. Remove the href= (by changing to a button)
5. There should be a html markeup that is not working properly
6. Sometimes Firebug and YSlow Firefox (FF) plugins can cause such issues
7. Check that you don’t have any image or another elements in View with empty src attribute (

And please check this link.

https://validator.w3.org/